# To change viscocity or not

Tags: honda, oil-change, fit, oil-viscosity

I recently made a post about switching to synthetic, but looking at the answers and information all around i decided that it was not worth it for me.

I have an 115.000 kms (70k miles more or less) 10 year old Honda Fit GD01 (2008) and in the manual says the viscocity of oil recommended should be 10w40.

Where i live we dont have -0C° (32 farenheit) anymore. Last time i remember was the earlies 2000. Minimum temperatures range from 0°C (extreme cases) to 38°C (around 104 farenheit) so I don't know really if 10w40 is the right oil.

I'm thinking about putting some 5w30 oil, but i'm not an expert.

Would you recommend this viscocity for my climate and car or it will suffer from it?

Comment: i’m surprised they don’t recommend 5w20. i’m in NY and we see temps like that. almost all hondas run 5w30, 5w20 or 0w20 here.

Comment: @ben really? where in NY does it never go below freezing?

Comment: @agentp not saying it doesn’t. the point was that we see similar temps with a lighter weight oil that’s used year round.

Comment: its not similar. You see 40F colder at least. You need the 5W- or 0W- he doesn't.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to change viscosity? Are you having problems with 10w40?

Comment: I dont have a problem with the current oil, but it is a brazilian brand that is not top quality so first of all i want to change brand and second, and strange enough, the manual says 10w30, but under the hood it says 5w40 or 10w40  and reading about on the internet i just thought that 5w30 would be best. But i cant know for sure because my lack of knowledge and i usually dont trust everything any mechanic tells me. The first one told me to use oil under the hood and another told to use 10w40 semi-synthetic Shell oil and leave 10w30 for winter.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, 10w-40 is totally fine for your climate. You can [refer to this](http://www.elf.com/en/advice-corner/engine-oil-faq/oil-viscosity-chart.html) as a rule of thumb guide. I always lean toward manufacturer spec, but you're temps aren't too extreme either way.

I live in Southern California (USA) and we all use the same oil year-round. That includes temps up to ~125F (~52C) in the summer and down to -20F (-29C) in the snowboarding season. For the most part myself and my friends run 10w-40 as factory spec (admittedly our temps are slightly outside spec for that oil), but some people will run SAE 50 for off-road summer toys... they can get *really* hot off-roading in the desert.